# Asymptotic expansion of integral of the form $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)e^{-\lambda f(x)}dx$

Tags: integration

I encountered these two integrals in a project I am working on. I was advised to try the stationary phase method, but I couldn't clearly see how that method might be applied to this particular question.

$$P(x) =\exp \Big[-\lambda \Big\{(x^2+\tfrac{1}{2})\sinh^{-1}x-\frac{\sinh(2\sinh^{-1}x)}{4} \Big\}  \Big],$$ where $\lambda$ is a large positive real number.

$$I_1=\int_{0}^{a} xP(x)dx$$

$$I_2=\int_{a}^{b} x^3P(x)dx,$$  where $a,b$ are positive real numbers.

Can these integrals be solved without using asymptotic expansion, or which asymptotic expansion method might I have to try?
Also, I wonder if it is possible to proceed with numerical methods. I have been trying to use Mathematica to solve this problem without much success.

Comment: Your problems are not for the method of stationary phase. Use the method of Laplace instead: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#iii Since your $f(x)$ is monotoically increasing for $x>0$, the cricitcal points for $I_1$ and $I_2$ are at $x=0$ and $x=a$, respectively.